# Using Jmeter How to Match values in Json response with JDBC response?

Tags: automated-testing, java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, json

**How to Match values in JSON response with JDBC response?**
just want to check that correct values passing in JSON response and need to verify that those values are matched with JDBC response (fetching data from Database). It is better to Explain with example.

Comment: Data validation type tests don't sound like they should be in JMeter?

Comment: is it possible in Jmeter? any comments others?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not knowing the details of JDBC and JSON response it is hard to provide exact configuration, from the high level perspective it should be something like:

1. Add [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) and store "interesting" part(s) of the response into JMeter Variable(s)
2. Add [JDBC PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_PostProcessor) and store values from the DB into JMeter Variable(s). See [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) guide to learn how to do it
3. Add [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) (one assertion per variable) to test if variables are equal. Make sure that assertions are placed **after** the JSON Extractor and JDBC PostProcessor:

   [image: Response Assertion JSON JDBC]

Comment: Appreciate your reply, Could you please provide me JSON Extractor and JDBC PostProcessor more details for this example? specially i want to know  about Variable_From_JSON and how it defined in JSON Extractor/HTTP request, .. so on..

Comment: You are asking for a story while I am limited to one chapter only. If you are not able to figure out the correct JSON/JDBC PostProcessors settings I would recommend starting separate question threads and it will be better to provide response data and highlight what parts you would like to store in JMeter Variables.

Comment: I have created separated thread for this Thank you !!    http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/25424/how-to-use-http-request-json-extractor-in-jmeter-with-response-assertion

Comment: Another thread  created for JDBC postProcessor. http://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/25427/jdbc-postprocessor-example-in-jmeter-for-response-assertion . kindly assist this.. thank you !!