# How to Use Http Request/JSON extractor(using Jmeter Variable) in Jmeter with Response assertion(using Jmeter Variable)

Tags: automated-testing, java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, json

How to Use  Http request/JSON extractor(using Jmeter Variable) in Jmeter with Response assertion(using Jmeter Variable). better to provide with Example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example you have the following response:

[image: JSON Response]

And you need to extract `John` from it.

1. Add [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) Post Processor
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Reference Name: anything meaningful, i.e. `name`
   - JSON Path Expressions: `$.name`

     [image: JSON Extractor example configuration]
3. That's it, you now have `${name}` JMeter Variable with the value of `John`

   [image: Variable from JSON Response]

If now you want to validate its value you can add a [Response Assertion](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion) and configure it like:

- Apply to -> JMeter Variable -> `name`
- Pattern Matching Rules: `Equals`
- Patterns to Test: `John`

[image: Response assertion for a JMeter Variable]

---

- To learn more about JSON Path check out this [Getting Started](https://github.com/jayway/JsonPath#getting-started) article.
- To see some advanced use cases (conditional select, matching multiple values in a single request, working with JSON Arrays) refer to [Advanced Usage of the JSON Path Extractor in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter) guide.

Comment: Excellent.... !!. I hope this will help to other Jmeter learners as well. cheers..!