# How do I save JMeter variables created at runtime?

Tags: automated-testing, java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, json

I'm using JMeter 3.1 to run a http-endpoint test & I need to extract a very small portion of the return JSON I receive.

I'm using the JSON Extractor postprocessor element & JSONPath expressions to find my value. [This post](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/25424/how-to-use-http-request-json-extractorusing-jmeter-variable-in-jmeter-with-res) does a *really* good job of explaining how to assign the value I'm looking for to a runtime variable.

However it stops short of explaining how to save said variable to an output file. I can check to make sure that I've pulled the data using an assertion rule; I can even save the true/false value of that check. Saving the variable itself however, seems less straightforward.

I have 3 ideas and am likely going to spend the next few hours exploring them & checking this thread. So,

### Will any of these work?:

- Figure out what "Sub Results" means to JMeter and see if I can get my JSON snippet there.
- Make another sampler that (somehow) just reads & returns a variable I pass it at runtime, whenever a thread executes.
- Figure out if "Assertion Results" is capable of saving anything other than "TRUE" or "FALSE."

[image: Here's an image!]

Comment: Can you give an example of data you receive and what exactly you need to save and how that is going to be used?

Comment: I'm running a "_server-blind_" test (aka I do not want the aid of my server-side metrics) against my web-API to see if I can determine server-side delivery-speed from a client. **There's a 0.04Kb dictionary from the 1Kb JSON response which I want in a csv field.**
I posted this to stackoverflow and got an answer re: putting vars into a csv. If you don't think it's a comprehensive answer, I'll hold-off posting it here. Here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43035806/how-do-i-save-jmeter-variables-created-at-runtime-specifically-a-snippet-of-js/43037917#43037917

Answer (score 1):

As it has never been added, the answer has been given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43035806/how-do-i-save-jmeter-variables-created-at-runtime-specifically-a-snippet-of-js/43037917#43037917

And see manual on [Sample variable](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)