# JDBC PostProcessor Example in Jmeter for Response assertion

Tags: automated-testing, java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, data-validation

How to Use JDBC PostProcessor(using Jmeter Variable) in Jmeter with Response assertion(using Jmeter Variable).Provide me with example..

Comment: I think you need to better articulate what your problem is and what issue you want to overcome.  In its current format it sounds more like you are asking for people to perform the development for you..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, we have the following table:

```
mysql> describe city;
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID          | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Name        | char(35) | NO   |     |         |                |
| CountryCode | char(3)  | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| District    | char(20) | NO   |     |         |                |
| Population  | int(11)  | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

And you are executing some query against it, i.e. getting all the information on 2 random cities:

```
select * from city order by rand() limit 2;
```

You need to configure JMeter like:

[image: JMeter JDBC Configuration]

Pay attention to the `Variable names` stanza

So when you execute the request, it will return raw data like:

[image: JDBC Raw data]

But given you defined variable names, you will have the following JMeter variables:

- `ID_1` with the value of `725`
- `ID_2` with the value of `3077`
- `Name_1` with the value of `Randburg`
- `Name_2` with the value of `Bremen`
- etc.

[image: JDBC Variables JMeter]

See [Debugging JDBC Sampler Results in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debugging-jdbc-sampler-results-jmeter) article for more details on working with JDBC Test elements output

Comment: Excellent Dimitri T nicely explained it. Thank you very much..!!